# NullPontException in android

Tags: android

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` for

```
ReadingDialog lblDialog=new ReadingDialog(ReadingModule.this);
ArrayAdapter myAdap = (ArrayAdapter) lblDialog._spinMat.getAdapter(); 
int spinnerPosition = myAdap.getPosition(myString);
lblDialog._spinMat.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```

`ReadingDialog` extends `Dialog`

Can anyone help me?

---

Application crashed in the second line

```
ArrayAdapter myAdap = (ArrayAdapter) lblDialog._spinMat.getAdapter();
```

Comment: paste your logcat here

Comment: Look at the stack trace you are getting or use a debugger (you can even place a breakpoint on NPE).

Comment: what is _spinMat? you do lblDialog._spinMat.getAdapter(); but I don't see where you initialize _spinMat

Comment: Please post you logcat and tell us which is the line referenced as causing the crash.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like lblDialog cannot be null, so you might want to check the following objects (in order):

- lblDialog
- lblDialog._spinMat
- myAdap

**Update**:

If the application crashed in

ArrayAdapter myAdap = (ArrayAdapter) lblDialog._spinMat.getAdapter();

Then I suggest you check the first two objects that I have listed. Make sure they are initialized or figure out why they are not.